# Can't OR 2 enum values of the same type outside its enum class declaration

Tags: enums

I am a newbie to both C++ and game programming. I am dealing with something I don't know how to make it work. I am coding along a game from a book, the authors didn't use **enum class** for his type but as recommended by most people, I am using **enum class** to remake it. It produces no error when I **OR** 2 enum value inside its **enum class** **scope** like this:

```
// This is inside the "Category.h" header file
namespace Category
{
    enum class Type
    {
        None              = 0,
        SceneAirLayer     = 1 << 0,
        PlayerAircraft    = 1 << 1,
        AlliedAircraft    = 1 << 2,
        EnemyAircraft     = 1 << 3,
        Pickup            = 1 << 4,
        AlliedProjectile  = 1 << 5,
        EnemyProjectile   = 1 << 6,

        Aircraft          = PlayerAircraft | AlliedAircraft | EnemyAircraft,
        Projectile        = AlliedProjectile | EnemyProjectile
    };
}
```

But when I try to **OR** them inside a function of another source file, the compiler produces an error,
that is: **"no operator "|" matches these operands operand type are Category::Type | Category::Type"**
and here is the code inside that function (the game works for the authors version enum without class)

```
void World::destroyEntitiesOutsideView()
{
    // This "command.category" just returns an "unsigned int" value
    Command command;
    // The error appears here
    command.category = static_cast<unsigned int>(Category::Type::Projectile | Category::Type::EnemyAircraft);

    // This is I just try to OR them alone but still the same error
    Category::Type::Aircraft | Category::Type::AlliedProjectile;
}
```

Please someone tell me why and how can I fix this error??? Thank you a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using enum class instead of just enum. "Class enum doesn’t allow implicit conversion to int, and also doesn’t compare enumerators from different enumerations"